# Convert a hex string to ascii string in php

Tags: php

I want to convert a "hex" String: `$hexstring = "8F21FF434927";`

into its ascii code: `!ÿCI'`

I found simple hex2str Methodes but they do an output like: `0x8F 0x21...`

Answer (score 1):

```
function hexToStr($hex){
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2){
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}
echo hexToStr("8F21FF434927");
```